# Cheat sheet, manual creator to look up commands I want to remember

Tags: windows, information-management, knowledge-base

I often find myself looking for what Linux command to use and have to google it again and then look up through long explanation to find the simple syntax I'm looking for.

Is there a desktop program for Windows that I can store list of items in it and search it easily?

For example click *Add new*, then write "To tar.   tar -cvf xx.tar files", then new item for untar. Then when I type in the search bar "tar", both show up.

I could write that in a notepad and use NetBeans to search it. It could get messy. And I'd rather have a simple application or plugin to NetBeans.  Any recommendation? Or should I write such an app?

Answer (score 4):

I use [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) for this.
It allows you to write these facts as question/answer:

[image: Anki add fact]

You can organize facts in decks, and also add tags if you have many and want to organize them better. You can search them by full-text search or browse the list or search by tags. See for instance how I search my "tech" deck for all [byobu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_(software)) commands:

[image: Anki deck browser search]

Free for Win/Mac/Linux/Android.
A web interface and iOS app are also available.
Convenient syncing between all.
Publicly available [bug tracker](https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions) ([Android](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/issues)).
Source code: Desktop: https://github.com/dae/anki, Android: https://github.com/ankidroid

As a bonus, it allows you to quizz yourself on the questions/answers. Its smart algorithm and flexible model actually makes Anki very efficient at this. The Jeopardy! all-time record for single-day was won in 2010 by a person who used Anki to memorize huge amounts of facts.

*Disclaimer: I am part of the open source team.*

Comment: It turns out that my decision to use Mnemosyne was mostly result of poor design of Anki website (for the first time in my life I see a bugtracker named "[Discussion Area](https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions/ankidesktop)"). And after finding it I am not sure whatever it can be described as bug tracker - ability to see only open issues is either missing or well hidden. I am not sure whatever source code repository is also well hidden or missing - only tarballs are available what is not inviting for a programmer.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny: The source code is on Github, I added links. I agree that the bug tracker of the desktop version is not great for programmers.

Answer (score 2):

[Mnemosyne](http://mnemosyne-proj.org/) is in the same class of software as Anki ([spaced repetition software](https://www.gwern.net/Spaced%20repetition)) and I prefer it because it is Open Source with publicly available [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mnemosyne-proj), so in the long run I expect less problems with access to my data.

Available for Windows/Linux/Mac OS X/Android/also other mobile platforms, but with tricky setup.

You can search by full-text or browse the list or search by tags, or search by full-text within specified tags.

Mnemosyne/Anki is designed to be tool for learning and remembering it for your entire life, but it may be also used as a fact database.

[image]